# Graphic card for developer box with 3 x WQXGA

Tags: graphics-cards, linux

I'm thinking about the HW for my new *Linux* developer computer. The only unclear part is the graphic card as I need it

- to support three monitors, each having

  - *2560 x 1600* pixels
  - and only *DualLink DVI* connectors
- be *low profile*

As noted in a comment, the CPU supports three monitors. However, I want a small computer and this requires a small main board and no such main board has three video connectors.

It should run smoothly for working and occasionally watching video, no gaming.

Probably related details:

- CPU Intel Core i7-7700K
- Ubuntu 18.04

Currently considered graphic cards:

- Sapphire R5 230 2GB DDR3 (low end AMD, preferred because of bad nVidia Linux compatibility)
- MSI GeForce GT 1030 2G LP OC, 2GB GDDR5 (assuming it can be used together with the on board graphic)
- PALiT GeForce GT 1030, 2GB GDDR5

Comment: Have you observed your integrated graphics (Intel HD 630) lagging out your computer when running your double 2K monitor setup? [This article](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/intel-hd-graphics-comparison) claims you can run a dual 2K setup without any problems. Even then the discrete graphics cards you are currently considering are probably overkill particularly if you're not gaming.

Comment: @BennettYeo I don't have anything yet. And it's triple monitor rather than dual.

Comment: Well the i7-7700K's iGPU is on the list that supports up to [3 monitors](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025672/graphics-drivers.html). Because your user case scenario is "working and occasionally watching video, no gaming" and you are thinking about hardware on the individual level (non-prebuilt), I think that you should hold off on buying a discrete GPU once you have the system built to try using the computer purely on the integrated GPU. From there, you can decide whether you want to spend the additional cash on a discrete card.

Comment: @BennettYeo Edited. The problem is that I've found no small main board having three connectors.

Comment: Are you: 1. looking for a specific GPU recommendation (including the ones you specified) alone, or 2. looking for a self-built-computer-parts type recommendation? Could you list a budget (particularly if your intention is No. 2)?

Comment: @BennettYeo I'm going to buy everything new, but all parts but the graphic card are already basically fixed. The total price will be something like $1500, mostly because of the CPU, 32 GB RAM and 1TB SSD. The price for the graphic card hardly matters as it'll be something cheap, if any. In case it matters, the chosen main board is ASUS ROG STRIX Z370-I GAMING - Intel Z370 (even though there'll be no gaming).

Comment: Are you looking for a "bill of materials" type recommendation for all the other parts you are going to buy new?